# Shell script to remove a word between "." and "," in the first line of a file

Tags: shell, csv

I have a CSV file which contains the first line in the following format.

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd,eee.fff.ggg.hhh,iii.jjj.kkk.lll,mmm.nnn.ooo.ppp
```

- Need to read the 1st line of the CSV file.
- Then, read the word between 3rd `.` and `,`, that is the output should look like below.
  `ddd,hhh,lll,ppp`
- Relace the above output as the first line in the CSV file.

I want to get this done on a shell script.

Thank you

Kiran Kumar G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[.,]' 'NR==1{s=$4; for(i=8; i<=NF; i+=4) s=s "," $i; print s}' file
ddd,hhh,lll,ppp
```

`-F '[.,]'` will make input field separator as `,` or `.`

`NR==1` will make it run for first record only.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for the solution, it worked fine for me as i needed this in shell script. One more information required, if the source string not regular pattern say -- aa.bb, cc.dd, ee.ff, gg.hh.ii.jj, kk.ll.mm.nn -- then how to get the word's before the "," ? Output should be -- bb, dd, ff, jj, nn. Request your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Maintain current IFS
OIFS=$IFS

# Read each CSV value into array
IFS=',' read -a array < path_to_file.csv    
replacementString=""

# Iterate through each item
for element in "${array[@]}"; do

    # Concatenate each last value of period separated values
    replacementString="$replacementString,$(echo $element | cut -d "." -f 4)"

done

# Replace first line with new string, minus leading comma
sed -i -e "1s/.*/${replacementString#?}/" path_to_file.csv  

# Restore original IFS
IFS=$OIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Perl:
Change the file name in the script and run with:

```
$ ./<script name>.pl > newfile.csv

#!/usrbin/perl -w

$thefile = "yourfile.csv";
open(CSV_FILE, $thefile) or
   die "\nError: cannot open file $thefile\n\n";

while ($line = <CSV_FILE>)
{
   if ($. == 1)
   {
       chomp($line);
       @comma_chunks = split(/,/,$line);
       foreach my $commachunk (@comma_chunks)
       {
           @dot_chunks = split(/\./,$commachunk);
           push(@last_dot_chunks, $dot_chunks[-1]); # last of the dotchunks 
       }
       $new_first_line = join(',', @last_dot_chunks);
       print "$new_first_line\n";
   }
   else
   {
       print $line;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Tie::File;
tie my @a, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[0] or die "$ARGV[0]:$!";
$a[0] =  join ",",  map { (split /\./)[3] } split ',', $a[0];
```

Call that script with your filename as the first argument.  If you insist on doing this with a shell script, it's probably easiest to just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

perl -e '
use Tie::File;
tie my @a, "Tie::File", $ARGV[0] or die "$ARGV[0]:$!";
$a[0] =  join ",",  map { (split /\./)[3] } split ",", $a[0];
' input-file
```

Although you should probably replace `input-file` with `$1` and pass the filename as the first argument.  `Tie::File` is a nice little module that maps the tied file to an array, so you can simply manipulate the elements of the array and have the changes made in the file.  In this case, we're just tying your input file to the array `@a` and then splitting the first field as you describe.